# Images or contents disappearing when scrolling using locomotive scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

So this is my first question so far. I'm building a static website from scratch. I'm ok-ishly knowledgable about html and css but I'm not really that amazing. (I'm still of a designer than developer.)

I'm using this locomotive for my smooth scrolling and parallax effect but either there's a bug or something is conflicting with the code (either my html structure or some bad styling) that makes the images at the end of the page disappearing. I can't trace the problem so anyone could please look through them would be great. THANKSSSSS!

**Edit 2**: So the problem is caused by using `data-scroll-section`, which is expected to improve performance/speed but it seems that there might be bugs. It removes out-of-view sections to save data which is understandable, though it might remove the sections prematurely. maybe some miscalculations?

After removing `data-scroll-section` and only using `data-scroll` with `data-scroll-speed`, everything works fine. Though a bit slow and glitchy. :/ Hope it will improve in the future.

**Edit 1**: To be clear, the plug-in works, just that the images are disappearing towards the end of the scrolling.

Links:

Whole folder: https://github.com/tranghasgit/sonya-web-test

Locomotive: https://github.com/locomotivemtl/locomotive-scroll

Comment: What browser are you your testing in? It would be well worth your time to hit the F12 key if you are in Chrome or Edge and learn to use the Developer Tools. You should be able to set breakpoints in your code  and debug your logic. Also be sure and check out the console tab for logging output - instrument your code with console.log("Message or variable here"); statements  - or for immediate variable /argument/object evaluation . You can also manipulate your CSS and find HTML elements, etc.

Comment: Mine was in Chrome. I did inspected it and no errors were shown. I will try some more of your suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution

```
html.has-scroll-smooth 
{
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;  
}
```

add this to the css and it will solve that element disappearing issues

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: How do you implement this style in tailwind?

Comment: @Phaki you'd add the tailwind classes to your html element: `<html class="overflow-hidden fixed inset-0">`